# Scrolling continues across workspaces

Tags: release-juno, desktop, workspace

If a start scrolling on an application in one workspace/desktop and then use the `super + rightarrow` to switch another workspace that has an application with scrollable content, the scrolling continues.

I think this is a bug and I'd be interested to hear how to fix it.

[image: Here's a reproduction of the bug.]

Answer (score 1):

Run dconf-editor and search for "mouse" entries.

Try to change some options like "acceleration time" or "mouse tracking mode".

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I playeed around with this setting and it didn't seem to fix the issue. What value did you set `accel-time` to?

Comment: The values I use are in the picture